# Is it a Diff or not?

Tags: code-golf

Your program will be run an undetermined amount of times. On all but the last, there will be a file called `data` in the same directory of your program that has the same value each time. On the last run, the file will be there but will have different data in it. On all the times *except* the last, you can do whatever you want, as long as the following rules are met:

- **Don't output anything**
- **Don't change `data` file**

On the *last* run, you must print out the diff of the first `data` file and the current `data` file.

**Rules:**

- **You *may* save whatever you want in any files you want, just don't edit the `data` file**

**Scoring:**

- **Lowest char score wins**

Cheating encouraged. You have *no* indication of which run you're in *except* that the `data` file is changed.

Comment: what's the definition of "diff"?

Comment: also, what is the possible contents of `data`? Can we assume it contains all alphanumeric characters?

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff

Comment: what I meant is, can we do something like `-olddata +newdata`? what is the format of the diff?

Comment: On all the times except the last, we don't output anything. How is the "last run" defined?

Comment: If you're saving a file, doesn't that contradict `Don't output anything`?

Comment: @KaranGoel The *last run* is defined as the one where the `data` is changed.

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow Assume you will be calling the `diff` utility.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Bash (31)

```
[ -e x ]&&diff data x;cp data x
```

Kinda obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is with good ol' Windows batch:

```
@echo off
  if exist lastdata goto compare_data
  type data > lastdata 
  goto end
:compare_data
  fc data lastdata > nul
  if errorlevel 1 goto last
  if errorlevel 0 goto end
:last
  fc data lastdata
  del lastdata
:end
```